# Get Multiple Checkbox and insert into Sql Database

Tags: php, sql, html, mysqli

I know I am annoying but your help will definitely make me a good developer one day so please please help me as you help in the previous questions so my today question is I am able to learn multiple checkboxes inserted in SQL database 
this is my HTML code

```
 <form action="" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and this works perfectly
with this is PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
     $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO students (attendance) VALUES ('".$selected."')");
    }
  } else {
      echo "nothing checked";
  }
}
?>
```

my problem is when is insert checkboxes the value of each checkbox inserted against each id I want to insert all values against one id so basically when someone selects all boxes the values inserted against one id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use **implode()** function to convert value from array to string.

Please try below solution.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){
  $selected = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);
  $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO students (attendance) VALUES ('".$selected."')");
}
?>
```

Hope this help.